# Trouble Appending Unique Identifiers To Objects In List

Tags: python, list, unique

I have a large data file and would like to append unique identifiers to recurring names (although there are 18k names). I've tried several ways including idfun but haven't found a solution that works. At current this is one of the things I've tried.
This is just as an example as I understand that y resets after each for loop and is not iterative (generator).

```
combined = []
for line in template: 
    if line.startswith(">"):
        broken = line.split(" ")
        entry = broken[0]
        combined.append(entry)
        x = 0
        y =+ x
        print entry + str(y)
```

I've seen this answer to the problem:

```
def f(seq, idfun=None): # Order preserving
  return list(_f(seq, idfun))

def _f(seq, idfun=None):  
  ''' Originally proposed by Andrew Dalke '''
  seen = set()
  if idfun is None:
    for x in seq:
      if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
  else:
    for x in seq:
      x = idfun(x)
      if x not in seen:
        seen.add(x)
        yield x
```

But don't really understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use a [hashing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html#module-hashlib) function.  A hash always returns the same output, given the same input, but will never give the same output to different inputs.  Thus, recurring words are given the same ID.

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> for word in ['beer','gin','beer']: print word, hashlib.md5(word).hexdigest()
... 
beer 3e1867f5aee83045775fbe355e6a3ce1
gin a6c72983f8a0a002155d67b12b345629
beer 3e1867f5aee83045775fbe355e6a3ce1
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realize you could do that. However the difficulty is that I'd like to make every recurring word have a different ID (so I can tell them apart). I actually figured out my own problem by just using a simple + j/ j+1.